# Emqx: Url not found

Tags: client, mqtt, messagebroker, emq

I downloaded `emqx-windows-v3.2.3` from [EMQ X Broker](https://www.emqx.io/downloads#broker) .

After unzip and start `C:\emqx\bin>emqx start` it, when I run its dashboard on chrome `http://localhost:18083` I got `URL not found` ...

What is the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be that your port 8080 is occupied, which causes the management module not to start successfully. Please check the 8080 listener before starting EMQ X.

Comment: Yes.It was occupied@wivwiv

Comment: In la las version 4.1.x they have moved to 8081 but still is busy, i have changed to 8090 in the file "plugins/emqx_management.conf" and all is right